# Auto placement of legend box with margin/padding

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to *automatically* place a legend box in a plot, but I'm still in trouble with it. I'd like to place the legend box close to the corner of the plot, but with a small padding/margin.

Using predefined positions, like `"topright"` or `"bottomleft"`, place the legend too close/upon the border of the plot, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930448/1655939);
and I find it amazingly upsetting to keep on trying pixel by pixel to reach a nice placement to the box, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8931732/1655939).

I was wondering if there was anyway to position the legend box based on the width of the plot itself, and not on `max/min` values. Something that would *automatically* position the legend about `p%` close to a defined corner. Is there anyway to do so in R? Or even a way to add some padding to predefined positions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `inset=` option to `legend`

> inset: inset distance(s) from the margins as a fraction of the plot
>             region when legend is placed by keyword.

E.g.:

```
plot(1:10)
legend("topleft","blah",inset=0.05)
```

If you would like to make sure that the legend is inset the same distance from the corner, dependent on the x:y ratio of your plot, you could do something a little more complicated like:

```
plot(1:10)
xyratio <- do.call("/",as.list(par("pin")))
inset.amount <- 0.05
legend("topleft","blah",inset=c(inset.amount,inset.amount * xyratio))
```

This will fall apart when you resize the plot device though.

[image]

Comment: If you wanted to "roll your own" you could have tried: `legend(par('usr')[3] +0.1*( par('usr')[4]-par('usr')[3]), par('usr')[4] -0.1*( par('usr')[4]-par('usr')[3]) ,legend="TEST")`

Comment: @DWin I was in fact expecting something like that, but long as `inset` is doing the job, guess it'll suffice. Thanks for the alternative, anyway. (:

Comment: @Rubens - I have updated to show another alternative that will allow you to specify an inset that is scaled to the x/y ratio of the plot.

Comment: @thelatemail And now I'll have to wait and start a bounty to reward your answer! (: Very nice job! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Rubens so much for the bounty xD

Comment: @MichaelChirico Like forever, ma non tanto! :D